# Github Webhook gives Service timeout error

Tags: jenkins, github, webhooks

I have created a webhook on my repository on Enterprise Github. The hook notifies commit event to Jenkins. But every time I commit on the branch following error comes

> We couldn’t deliver this payload: Service Timeout

I have set the payload URL as:
http://jenkins_server_ip:port/github-webhook (my jenkins runs on http)

Also I noticed the following message on Jenkins

[image: jenkins]

Answer (score 0):

I think GitHub webhook requires that the url be a https because by default it will do SSL verification.

Comment: Any solution to this? Even with https, it is not working for me. Getting the same error.

Comment: @Prernashah I ended up using smee.io. I was having a firewall issue. See this guide -> https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/01/07/webhook-firewalls/